# Insert into a temp table with resultsets data

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have a query which has many columns and some are computed value columns, i am trying to insert the values of those into temptorary table,

and then alter the temp table to drop a column

and query the table again to display just select records.

Here is what i tried

```
<cfset rs = getmyData()>
<cfquery name="rs" datasource="#dsn#">
        SELECT * INTO #TemporaryTable FROM #rs#

        ALTER TABLE #TemporaryTable DROP COLUMN name,email

        SELECT Distinct * FROM #TemporaryTable 

        DROP TABLE #TemporaryTable 
</cfquery>
```

but probleming happening when it is not getting passed the query object to insert the values in to the temp table

getting an error, rs

```
Can't cast Complex Object Type Query to StringUse Built-In-Function "serialize(Query):String" to create a String from Query The error
```

Comment: So `rs` has data. You need to do a query of query and you need to focus on the columns you do want

Comment: yeah, seems like i cannot do the temporary table solution

Comment: The temporary table stuff doesn't appear to be necessary.  In fact, if the `cfset` command results in a query object named `rs`, you can then use the `QueryDeleteColumn` function to get rid of the unwanted columns before attempting to serialize the results - if in fact that is what you are attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with the approach.

Consider

1. Doing entire query within SQL query

OR

2. Using `QueryDeleteColumn()` to remove unneeded column